# What's the difference between L2TP and L2TPv3?

Tags: mpls, tunnel, l2tp, l2vpn

Is L2TPv3 an improvement of L2TP or a completely different technology? Other than "it scales better" and "the non-proprietary *MPLS*" I can't find much information about it that's not a Cisco configuration tutorial.

Can it handle network changes like IKEv2? *[…but, on layer 2]*

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say that it is a 'new protocol heavily based on L2TPv2'. It shares a lot of the messages, constructs, flows with L2TPv2 but it is not strictly backwards compatible. It does have an L2TP 'compatibility' scheme as indicated in [section 4.7 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3931#section-4.7), but that comes with limitations.

The most significant changes are actually listed directly in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3931#section-1.1):

> Notable differences between L2TPv2 and L2TPv3 include the following:
>
> Separation of all PPP-related AVPs, references, etc., including a portion of the L2TP data header that was specific to the needs of PPP.  The PPP-specific constructs are described in a companion document.
>
> Transition from a 16-bit Session ID and Tunnel ID to a 32-bit Session ID and Control Connection ID, respectively.
>
> Extension of the Tunnel Authentication mechanism to cover the entire control message rather than just a portion of certain messages.

Your second question is unclear, network changes is a very generic term. Very high-level:

- L2TPv3 over IP/UDP can obviously handle any network change between L2TP endpoints, as long as there is IP connectivity.
- L2TPv3 can handle any L2 change at both endpoints, as long as the endpoints themselves don't change.
- L2TPv3 can not dynamically change the endpoint for an ongoing session, so suppose your L2 changes in such a way that L2 traffic ends up at a new endpoint, that would require a new L2TP tunnel as far as I know.